# Gradle Exec task and process output

Tags: python, process, gradle, stdout, build.gradle

I have a python script which prints some strings and updates it's execution progress in console:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...

    print 'Hello, world!'

    while page <= pages:
        ...

        done = float(page) / pages
        sys.stdout.write('\r[{0:50s}] {1:.2f}%'.format('#' * int(done * 50), done * 100))

        page += 1

    print ''
```

When I run it from console like `python script.py` everything is ok and I can see output and progressbar. I need to run this script as a part of Gradle build, so, I've created a task:

```
task process(type: Exec) {
    workingDir file('src/main/python')
    commandLine 'python', 'process.py', ...
}
```

Now, when I use `gradle process` to execute the script I see no output in console, the last line that is printed is `> Building 0% > :process`

I've tried to use Java 7's `ProcessBuilder` with no luck too:

```
task process << {
    def processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder([
            'python',
            'process.py',
            ...
    ]).directory(file('src/main/python'))
            .redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
            .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
            .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT).start().waitFor()
}
```

I'm stuck. I really want to see python's output in the same console. How can I achieve it?

UPD: sometimes it somehow prints gibberish: [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I worked around this issue by flushing the system output in the python script.  it's not the ideal solution, but it gets the job done.

So I have the following in my python script

```
import sys
import time

def flush_out(string):
    print(string)
    sys.stdout.flush()

#script does something
flush_out("Waiting for 10 seconds...")
time.sleep(10)
flush_out("Exiting")
sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution for me was to redirect output to the file:

```
  .redirectErrorStream(true)
  .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to(new File(project.buildDir, "my-task.log")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the question is old, this may be relevant to others. My solution is to explicitely start a shell with "-c" parameter to let the shell process the parameters. This even allows to redirect STDERR and STDOUT.

Here is an example:

```
task(createVersionFile, type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'sh', '-c', "echo ${version} > ${htmlDir}/version.txt"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I sees this post, posted 7 years ago. The solution is to hook up the `System.out` like this:

```
def sqlplus = "sqlplus ${db.un}/${db.pw}@${db.tns} @upgrade.sql".execute(null, new File('file/path/'))

sqlplus.withWriter { writer ->
    writer.write("exit")
}

sqlplus.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err) // This is the trick

sqlplus.waitFor()
if (sqlplus.exitValue() != 0) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error updating database")
}
```