# How could a command line tool print to console without stdout or stderr?

Tags: windows, cmd, stdout

I've got a Windows CLI EXE that prints to the console when I run it.
This is not a program I can modify.

I wrapped this in a gradle Exec task, and it clearly is running, but nothing is getting printed to the screen. I had not configured anything special with the output.

I ran the program directly again but used `1>` and `2>` to redirect stdout and stderr to files.

Because this program takes 3 hours to run I hit Ctrl-C after a while and opened the redirect files.

None of the usual output was in the files.

Could it be using backspace or some other mechanism to prevent output from capture? The output does not clear on the actual console. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981036/gradle-exec-task-and-process-output try adding "Console.Out.Flush()" after writing to the console.  Also, are you doing anything weird in the exec def, like in the sample https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html where they're replacing the stdout with a buffer?

Comment: @Will This isn't my program

Comment: You might want to add the definition of the task to your question.  At this point, I'm at the end of my knowledge. Good luck.

Comment: @Will it's just an Exec that runs a command, nothing else. Besides gradle doesn't have anything to do with it. It happens with `2>` and `1>` as well

Comment: It looks like it's the same issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990851/unable-to-redirect-output-message-in-windows-command-prompt-cmd-exe but I'm not able to close this as a duplicate, for some reason I can't get that to show up as an option. Mercury must be in retrograde.

Comment: That question doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer, so nobody can VTC as a dupe of that.  If you have an answer to your question, you can simply add it below and close this out after the waiting period.  At least it'll be a dupe-able target at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another program by the same author that does not take as long, so I was able to let it finish.

The program does in fact write to stdout, but it doesn't flush until the very end. Which would be 3 hours for the program in the question! I would have thought that flushing would impact the console as well as a redirect stream, but it appears to only impact redirects. This makes sense if you wanted to have an animated progress spinner or something like that. Since I can't update the program code.

It looks like I'm just stuck with no progress updates.

Comment: Most standard I/O libraries default to full buffering when writing to a pipe or file and line buffering when writing to a console or TTY. stderr should always use either no buffering or line buffering. If piped stdout is unavoidably buffered, one option is to set its stdout to a console screen buffer and scrape its contents as the program writes to it.

Comment: @eryksun it's not that important as I can live with the status quo, but do you have a link to how to "set its stdout to a console screen buffer"? In particular what do you mean by "it"?

Comment: It would require calling native WinAPI functions such as `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`, which may be difficult or impossible to integrate into Gradle. I wouldn't know.